# How do you call a method that checks enum values from another script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity and I'm trying to call a method that checks enum values from a separate script.

I have two cubes with different enum values but when I call this function, only the first enum value is read instead of both of them.

**OtherScript.cs:**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class OtherScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    Test test;

    private void Awake()
    {
        test = FindObjectOfType<Test>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        test.PrintCubeNames();
    }
}
```

**Test.cs:**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum CubeName { Bill, Ted }
    public CubeName cubeName;

    public void PrintCubeNames()
    {
        print(cubeName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow -- It would help everyone out if you copy and pasted your code in to your post. Looking at a desktop-sized image is not ideal for us old folks who have garbage eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Your property `cubeName` is just taking the first default value of your declared enum (which in this case would be `Bill`). To print all of the cube names you would need to declare a property with a list of enums like so:

Replace:

```
public CubeName cubeName;
```

with:

```
private List<CubeName> CubeNameList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CubeName)).Cast<CubeName>().ToList();
```

Then in your `PrintCubeNames()`:

```
public void PrintCubeNames()
{
   foreach(var cubeName in CubeNameList) 
   {
      print(cubeName);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your enum to a string array using `Enum` static method [GetNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getnames?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Enum_GetNames_System_Type_).

Example:

```
public void PrintCubeName()
{
    var listName = Enum.GetNames(typeof(CubeName)).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < listName.Count; i++)
    {
        print(listName[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Links are generally not excepted as answers, because they could become unusable.